# Does Firefox expose an assertion library to extension authors?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox4

I'm writing a Firefox extension and am wondering about the best way to assert my application's invariants. From what I understand if I set `browser.dom.window.dump.enabled = true` in about:config, then `window.dump()` becomes available for logging (is this the recommended way to do the equivalent of `console.log()`?) but I'm wondering if there is an actual assertions library.

If not it's easy enough to write a tiny function that logs an error and throws an exception, but a built-in alternative would be cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [nsIDebug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDebug) which allows you to generate run-time assertions and aborts, but that may be overkill for what you want.

The recommended way to log is to use Services.console.logStringMessage (or its equivalent in older Firefox versions) or Components.reportError, both of which log to the Error console.

Comment: Well, if you just throw, then that will be logged to the Error console, but I'm not sure that's what you meant.